# pandas create dataframe - parse key

Tags: python, pandas

I have this file:

```
:Product: Solar Radio Data             7day_rad.txt
:Issued: 0922 UTC 05 Feb 2016
#
# Prepared by the U.S. Dept. of Commerce, NOAA, Space Weather Prediction Center
# Please send comments and suggestions to SWPC.Webmaster@noaa.gov
#  Units: 10^-22 W/m^2/Hz
#  Missing Data:  -1
#
#    Daily local noon solar radio flux values - Updated once an hour
#
  Freq  Learmonth  San Vito  Sag Hill  Penticton  Penticton  Palehua  Penticton
   MHZ   0500 UTC  1200 UTC  1700 UTC   1700 UTC   2000 UTC  2300 UTC  2300 UTC


2016 Jan 30
   245       20        17        17         -1         -1        12        -1
   410       38        34        37         -1         -1        35        -1
   610       56        -1        56         -1         -1        50        -1
  1415      104        73        72         -1         -1        78        -1
  2695      106       106        98         -1         -1       101        -1
  2800       -1        -1        -1        105        105        -1       105
  4995       -1       149       134         -1         -1       145        -1
  8800      287       269       261         -1         -1       275        -1
 15400      514       573       536         -1         -1       515        -1


2016 Jan 31
   245       21        18        20         -1         -1        32        -1
   410       39        17        38         -1         -1        46        -1
   610       58        -1        56         -1         -1        60        -1
  1415       91        74        72         -1         -1        78        -1
  2695      102       103        97         -1         -1       100        -1
  2800       -1        -1        -1        102        101        -1       100
  4995       -1       146       135         -1         -1       138        -1
  8800      278       268       262         -1         -1       272        -1
 15400      513       568       530         -1         -1       521        -1


2016 Feb 1
   245       25        21        21         -1         -1        35        -1
   410       45        40        40         -1         -1        49        -1
   610       66        -1        59         -1         -1        63        -1
  1415       65        72        68         -1         -1        78        -1
  2695       99       101        90         -1         -1        97        -1
  2800       -1        -1        -1        100        100        -1       100
  4995       -1       140       131         -1         -1       139        -1
  8800      278       258       266         -1         -1       275        -1
 15400      508       565       528         -1         -1       526        -1


2016 Feb 2
   245       23        20        21         -1         -1        36        -1
   410       45        68        40         -1         -1        48        -1
   610       68        -1        60         -1         -1        61        -1
  1415       72        73        69         -1         -1        80        -1
  2695       98        98        93         -1         -1       102        -1
  2800       -1        -1        -1        102        102        -1       103
  4995       -1       141       131         -1         -1       141        -1
  8800      284       255       268         -1         -1       276        -1
 15400      510       568       537         -1         -1       526        -1


2016 Feb 3
   245       34        -1        20         -1         -1        36        -1
   410       47        -1        41         -1         -1        50        -1
   610       70        -1        63         -1         -1        66        -1
  1415       68        76        76         -1         -1        86        -1
  2695      105        -1       106         -1         -1       112        -1
  2800       -1        -1        -1        113        112        -1       112
  4995       -1        -1       140         -1         -1       152        -1
  8800      284        -1       260         -1         -1       284        -1
 15400      516        -1       455         -1         -1       535        -1


2016 Feb 4
   245       -1        23        21         -1         -1        46        -1
   410       -1        43        43         -1         -1        54        -1
   610       -1        -1        65         -1         -1        68        -1
  1415       -1        84        81         -1         -1        90        -1
  2695       -1       114       120         -1         -1       118        -1
  2800       -1        -1        -1        125        123        -1       120
  4995       -1       162       154         -1         -1       158        -1
  8800       -1       276       273         -1         -1       283        -1
 15400       -1       564       523         -1         -1       547        -1


2016 Feb 5
   245       34        -1        -1         -1         -1        -1        -1
   410       52        -1        -1         -1         -1        -1        -1
   610       78        -1        -1         -1         -1        -1        -1
  1415       84        -1        -1         -1         -1        -1        -1
  2695      115        -1        -1         -1         -1        -1        -1
  2800       -1        -1        -1         -1         -1        -1        -1
  4995       -1        -1        -1         -1         -1        -1        -1
  8800      295        -1        -1         -1         -1        -1        -1
 15400      508        -1        -1         -1         -1        -1        -1
```

and now I need create data frame where I can read date data a time from pentiction...I can create dataframe and parse it with datetime but in this case dont work it...

Any suggestion pls?

Comment: Data block have always 10 rows?

Comment: hello jezrael...my savior:-)...yes always 10 rows...

Comment: Columns are always `8`?

Comment: yes always 8 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 sep="\s+",
                 skip_blank_lines=True,
                 index_col=None, 
                 skiprows=14, 
                 header=None,
                 names=['Freq','a','b','c','d','e','f','g'])
print df

     Freq    a    b    c    d    e    f    g
0    2016  Jan   30  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1     245   20   17   17   -1   -1   12   -1
2     410   38   34   37   -1   -1   35   -1
3     610   56   -1   56   -1   -1   50   -1
4    1415  104   73   72   -1   -1   78   -1
5    2695  106  106   98   -1   -1  101   -1
6    2800   -1   -1   -1  105  105   -1  105
7    4995   -1  149  134   -1   -1  145   -1
8    8800  287  269  261   -1   -1  275   -1
9   15400  514  573  536   -1   -1  515   -1
10   2016  Jan   31  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11    245   21   18   20   -1   -1   32   -1
12    410   39   17   38   -1   -1   46   -1
13    610   58   -1   56   -1   -1   60   -1
14   1415   91   74   72   -1   -1   78   -1
15   2695  102  103   97   -1   -1  100   -1
```